# Как реализовать перемещение рисунока за курсором?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы рисунок, который я нарисовал (обычный квадрат) двигался за курсором. Подскажите, как реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener('mousemove',function(ev){(function(e){
 e.style.left = ev.clientX+"px";
 e.style.top = ev.clientY+"px";
})(document.getElementById('box'))},false);
```

```html
<img id="box" style="position:fixed;" src="http://old.rk.karelia.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/chernyiy-kvadrat.jpg" width="50" height="50">
```